# jQuery .inArray If/Else Always Returning -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I'm trying to check if a value exists already. However even though values exist it's still returning -1. I'm trying to get my if/else statement working that if an item exists it "alerts" and if doesn't it runs the function addItem();

```
$(".detail-view button").on("click", function () {
    itemExists();

    function itemExists() {
        var detailID = $(this).attr('id');
        var itemArr = [];
        $("input#lunchorder_item_entry_id").each(function (index) {
            var lunchItemID = $(this).val();

            itemArr.push(lunchItemID);
        });

        addItem();

        alert(jQuery.inArray(detailID, itemArr));

        /*
        if (jQuery.inArray(detailID, itemArr)) {
            alert("You have already added this item. If you want to change item details, please remove the item and re-add it to your cart. Thank You!");
        } else {
            // the element is not in the array
            addItem();
        } */

        console.log(itemArr);
    }
```

Comment: Check the scope of your vars.

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I'm fairly new to jQuery.

Comment: What does `addItem` do?

Comment: addItem is the function that adds the values to the hidden input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `detailID` and `itemArr` are local to the function `itemExists()` and is `undefined` where your `if` condition is.

Moving it outside, should fix it.

```
...
var detailID = $(this).attr('id'); 
var itemArr = [];
function itemExists() {
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: If i move those variables outside the function I get `Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Are you telling me that is not what i'm getting? and my if/else is within that function.

Comment: I apologize I didn't move it outside of the click function, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

> However even though values exist it's still returning -1

I don't know how to proof that since you didn't provide any sample input. Yet, in the way your are calling `itemExists` the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is `undefined`/`window`, and `$(this).attr('id')` probably results `undefined`.

To fix that, either use `itemExists.call(this)` or store the DOM element (or even `$(this)`?) in a local variable and use that, or even move `itemExists` outside your handler and invoke it with explicit arguments.

> I'm trying to get my if/else statement working that if an item exists…

As you noticed, the returned index is `-1`. That means to check whether an element is contained in the array you will need to compare against -1, not cast every non-zero number to `true`:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(detailID, itemArr) != -1)
```

Comment: Sample input `var itemArr = ["7267", "7799", "8888"];`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then please `console.log(detailID)` as well and post it here.

Comment: Don't forget that second issue!